# Applying prerecorded animations to models with the same skeleton

Tags: 2d, animation, models, procedural, skeletal-animation

well my question sounds a bit like, how do I apply mo-cap animations to my model, but thats not really it I guess. Animations and model share the same skeleton, but the models vary in size and proportion, but I still want to be able to apply any animation to any model. I think this should be possible since the models got the same skeleton bone structure and the bones are always in the same area only their position varies from model to model.

In particular Im trying to apply this to 2D characters that got 2arm, 2legs, a head and a body, but if you got anything related to that topic even if its 3D related or keywords, articles, books whatever Im gratefull for everything cause Im a bit stuck at the moment.

cheers

Jery

Comment: It would help if you described your current troubles with the process. What have you tried? What's not working about it? You have animations on a single skeleton working already?

Comment: There was no trouble because I didnt know where to start. I was trying to code a auto-rigging function for characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the compsci literature, this problem is known as "motion retargeting", and in general it is quite difficult. If I recall, the most basic thing you can do is to naively transfer the joint parameters to the new skeleton, and then use IK to enforce whatever constraints you care about in your specific situation. So, if your character is supposed to be touching something, or stepping on a certain point on the ground, you can post-process this in. Of course, this doesn't always work, but for smaller skeletal deformations you can get away with a lot.

Anyway, here's a link to a Siggraph paper on the subject from 1998: http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~parent/classes/788/Sp06/OldStuff/Lectures/MotionCapture/Retarget/retarget-preprint.pdf

Comment: jeah I posted this in another forum aswell and they gave me a similar answers, yours is better thought - thanks alot! For now I will auto-rig the character and then retarget the joints only for rotating them, this wont be the final solution but for now it provides results I can work with. Things like the ground hitpoint are things that the physics system currently takes care about =)